# Weblogic is not replacing spring app-congig place holder value

Tags: spring, weblogic

I have eclipse and weblogic running in it.

I have added a project in that weblogic. Then I started the server

`${prop.dir}\filename` - cannot find the path specified, IO Exception

Then I have added VM argument in weblogic server

```
 Server View --> Double click server --> Open launch configuration --> 
 Arguments --> Add new arguments

 key: -Dprop.dir
 value: C:\Users\pathtoDirectoryWhichContainsMyPropertyFile
```

The same error still exists. I found that weblogic is not accepting this argument.

How do I resolve this issue? Any suggestions.

Comment: They key should be `prop.dir` not `-Dprop.dir`. Have you tried hard coding it to see if it works anyway?

Comment: Hi, I didn't mention that. I have tried that also. It's not working. I have added my file into project classpath and tried. File IO error is resolved. But property missing error is present. But that property is present in that file. So I guess file is not loading.